# State/Toggling variables in tmux

Tags: tmux

I was wondering if there is a way of defining a state variable in ./tmux.conf, such that depending on this variable, the keyboard binding would invoke a different command.

For example, I would like to use `M-F` to toggle the maximization of a pane in tmux (if the pane is not maximized, M-F would maximize it, otherwise it will unmaximize it)

Here is the pseudo-code that I have so far:

```
# Maximize pane: -------
# IF PANE_MAXIMIZED=False: 
# THEN: PANE_MAXIMIZED=True, and:
bind -n M-F new-window -d -n tmux-zoom  \; swap-pane -s tmux-zoom.0 \; select-window -t tmux-zoom

# Unmaximize pane -------
# IF PANE_MAXIMIZED=True: 
# THEN: PANE_MAXIMIZED=False, and:
bind -n M-F last-window \; swap-pane -s tmux-zoom.0 \; kill-window -t tmux-zoom
```

Comment: Not a big tmux user but I doubt it, as implementing a near Turing complete interpreter is a big task.  You could do this using an environment variable and shell scripts (calling tmux commands) though, since the shell is such an interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `run-shell` command to execute arbitrary shell commands, so this is certainly possible. [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/433702/66346) has a great example of this.

If all you're looking for is to toggle maximizing a window, as of version 1.8 that's a native tmux feature by use of the `-Z` flag to `resize-pane` (see [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/576505/66346)).

It's bound to <kbd>tmux-prefix</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> by default on my installation (via Homebrew on OS X).